# In Vuepress is there a terse way to include components?

Tags: vuepress

In Vuepress I can include components into the Markdown doing this:

```
<template>
    <div class="thingy">
        <Thingy/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Thingy from '../../components/Thingy'
export default {
  components: {Thingy},
}
</script>
```

However it's quite long-winded. Is there a way to do this more tersely?

I suspect not at the moment and I was wondering if I could come up sith something and submit a pull request, but to be honest I haven't a clue how to implement that **so any ideas would also be gratefully received**.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the component in `/.vuepress/components/`, Vuepress will register the component for you and you can just use it the markdown. The tag name is the same as the .vue file, so `MyComponent.vue` is used as

```html
<MyComponent></MyComponent>
```

If you want to locate the component elsewhere, use **enhanceApp.js** as shown here [vuepress - How to custom location of components directory...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987732/vuepress-how-to-custom-location-of-components-directory-vuepress-components)