# vuepress - How to custom location of components directory '.vuepress/components' with register-components?

Tags: vue.js, components, customization, vuepress

I tried to add custom directory of components in vuepress with plugin register/components but it seems not possible.

I tried with

```
module.exports = {
  title: 'Hello VuePress',
  description: 'Just playing around',
  plugins: [
   [
     'register-components',
     {
       componentDir: '../components'
     }
   ]
  ]
}
```

with this architecture (I want to select "components" directory)

[image]

But it seem doesn't work because the component is not recognized

[image]

I think that I wrote well my component in my base-button.md

[image]

Is that someone could help me to tell me steps to get there?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can register components globally in `enhanceApp.js` (which should be located in the `/.vuepress/` folder) in the same way you register them in a Vue app.

**enhanceApp.js**

```js
import BaseButton from '../../components/BaseButton'

export default ({
  Vue, // the version of Vue being used in the VuePress app
  options, // the options for the root Vue instance
  router, // the router instance for the app
  siteData // site metadata
}) => {
  Vue.component('BaseButton', BaseButton)
}
```